# How to put parser.addoption in a test module, not in conftest.py?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytest

I have the following

`conftest.py`:

```
def pytest_addoption(parser):
    parser.addoption('--sopt', action='store', default=None, help='Source Data Storage')
```

`my_test.py`:

```
@pytest.fixture(scope='module', autouse=True)
def sopt(pytestconfig):
    return pytestconfig.getoption('sopt')


def test_mtest(sopt):
    //pytest code
```

When running this test it works fine `python3 -m pytest --sopt=aaaaa`, but when moving

```
def pytest_addoption(parser):
    parser.addoption('--sopt', action='store', default=None, help='Source Data Storage')
```

from `conftest.py` to `my_test.py` it does not work and fails with the following error:

```
ERROR: usage: __main__.py [options] [file_or_dir] [file_or_dir] [...]
__main__.py: error: unrecognized arguments: --sopt=aaaaa
```

I don't like to have a separate file for just 2 lines of code.

**Is there a way to put `parser.addoption` from `conftest.py` into`my_test.py` and make it work?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. Referencing the [`pytest_addoption`](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/reference.html#_pytest.hookspec.pytest_addoption) hook documentation:

> #### Note:
>
> This function should be implemented only in plugins or `conftest.py` files situated at the tests root directory due to how pytest [discovers plugins during startup](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/writing_plugins.html#pluginorder).